Is this function checking if a blockhash has expired using wrong calculation?
The following function to check if a blockhash is expired is from QuickNode. But is it wrong?
async function isBlockhashExpired(connection: Connection, lastValidBlockHeight: number) {
    let currentBlockHeight = (await connection.getBlockHeight('finalized'));
    console.log('                           ');
    console.log('Current Block height:             ', currentBlockHeight);
    console.log('Last Valid Block height - 150:     ', lastValidBlockHeight - 150);
    console.log('--------------------------------------------');    
    console.log('Difference:                      ',currentBlockHeight - (lastValidBlockHeight-150)); // If Difference is positive, blockhash has expired.
    console.log('                           ');

    return (currentBlockHeight > lastValidBlockHeight - 150);
}

Solana requires that a transaction's blockhash is not older than 150 slots. So, shouldn't we use this calculation instead? :
return (currentBlockHeight - lastValidBlockHeight > 150)

Related: Why is LastValidBlockHeight 300 blocks ahead than current BlockHeight if hashes expire in 150?

This is currently the case because the reported lastValidBlockHeight is actually too high, but this was fixed in https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/pull/1034, which is part of the Agave 2.0 release.
2.0 is currently used on testnet only, but once it hits mainnet, the behavior will be correct, and you won't have to subtract 150 from the last valid block height reported by getLatestBlockhash, which is what the QuickNode code is doing.
